# How to use GeolocationPosition correctly in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, w3c-geolocation

We want to access the user's location using the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Geolocation).

This snippet works fine:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position: GeolocationPosition) => console.log(position));
}
```

VSCode also doesn't show any errors or warnings, but the Angular CLI throws this error:

> Cannot find name 'GeolocationPosition'.
> navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position: GeolocationPosition) => console.log(position));

The project is using the following things:

- Angular 11.0.6
- tslib 2.0.0
- ts-node 8.3.0
- tslint 6.1.0
- typescript 4.0.2

Also `strict` type checking is enabled in Angular CLI

*How to use this type and other types from that API correctly?*

Comment: Sometimes its easier to simply allow TS to infer the type `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => console.log(position));`. This way TS will automatically set the type correctly

Comment: But If I pass the value to a function, like `this.log(position);` and the method looks like this: `log(position: GeolocationPosition): void { console.log(position); }` I still need the type in the function definition. If I simply use `log(position) { }`, the compiler will say the type of `position` is missing and when I add `:any` the type is unknown in the method. Hope you understand my dilemma, @OwenKelvin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running TypeScript in v4.0.x brings up `Position` as the typename, but that appears to have been renamed to `GeolocationPosition` in 4.1.x. Can't find any docs on why they did that. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66005573/510048.

Recommend updating to the latest version of Typescript (currently 4.2.3)

Comment: Can confirm this.... thanks @MikeMurko

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the native `Position` type:

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position: Position) => console.log(position));
}
```