# Angular 11: Why can't the compiler find 'GeolocationPosition' during compiling? "Cannot find name 'GeolocationPosition'"

Tags: angular, geolocation, angular11

Why does the angular compiler can't find `GeolocationPosition` and `GeolocationPositionError`? VSC doesn't give an error and only during compiling it gives me an error.

```
Error: src/app/modules/shared/services/position.service.ts:10:46 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'GeolocationPosition'.

10   private positionSource = new ReplaySubject<GeolocationPosition>(1);
```

I worked around this by putting the `any` type instead, but I'm just curious why Angular is giving me the error and how I can fix this.

I've already tried different compiler targets (`es5`, `es6`, `es2018`) but with no luck. Already installed `@types/core-js` but also without any luck. Is there any @types module that I'm missing perhaps?

This is my current tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to fix your imports

Comment: @RachidO I assume the import of `GeolocationPosition`? Which package provides this?

Comment: Did you find the answer? Just hit this myself

Comment: @fieldhof If my answer helped you then please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In typescript 4.0.x this type was called `Position`. In typescript 4.1.x it was renamed to `GeolocationPosition`.

I think you'll find that your VS Code is using its built in version of typescript and that your project is using an earlier version.

To fix:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript@4.1.2
```

Comment: take note that you probably will have to update angular as well as the earlier minor versions of angular 11 require typescript up to version 4.1.0

Comment: IntelliJ: Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Typescript. Select a version, and use the `npm install --save-dev typescript@x.y.z` to ensure node isi the same as IntelliJ.

Comment: Replacing GeolocationPosition with Position fixed the issue. thanks

Comment: what about ts 5?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved changing local Angular CLI used by project.
**Explanation**:
I updated to Angular 11, but I forgot to update Angular CLI. The `ng build` gave me this output:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (9.1.7) is greater than your local
version (9.1.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.
```

**Steps**:
Update Angular CLI (if necessary)

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Update npm

```
npm install -g npm
```

Then `ng build` output become:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (11.1.2) is greater than your local version (9.1.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.
```

Install npm-check-updates

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
```

Execute `ncu -u` to view packages to update.
Execute `npm install` to update all packages.
After this, all should work.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change version of ol and ol types from "^6.5.0" to exact version "6.5.0",

"ol": "6.5.0",
@types/ol": "6.5.0",

Newer packages have breaking change with GeolocationPositionError type.

Angular 9 - with typescript ~3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

If you are using typescript version below 4, then replacing **GeolocationPosition** with **Position** will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still using Angular <= 11 and want to futureproof your code, declare the following interfaces

```js
export interface GeolocationCoordinates {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  altitude: number | null;
  accuracy: number;
  altitudeAccuracy: number | null;
  heading: number | null;
  speed: number | null;
}

export interface GeolocationPosition  {
  coords: GeolocationCoordinates;
  timestamp: number;
}
```

You can then use `GeolocationPosition` in place of `Position` while preventing it from breaking after an upgrade.